# How to get bearer token passed through header in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, bearer-token

In my rails application I'm able to get the Token `Authorization: Token token='aUthEnTicAtIonTokeN'` passed in header of request with

```
authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
 @auth_token = token
end
```

but when I pass token as `Authorization: Bearer token='aUthEnTicAtIonTokeN'` getting token as nil above method.

how can i get bearer token passed through header in rails application?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could get the Bearer token with a method like:

```
def bearer_token
  pattern = /^Bearer /
  header  = request.headers['Authorization']
  header.gsub(pattern, '') if header && header.match(pattern)
end
```

Also, when setting the header it should be:

```
Authorization: Bearer 'aUthEnTicAtIonTokeN'
```

Answer (score 9):

Your method will work correctly as it is, you just need to use the correct quotes in the request.

Using single quotes `'` doesn't work, where as double quotes `"` does.

For reference, rails handles tokens from the `Authorization:` header in any of the following formats with the `authenticate_with_http_token` method:

```
Bearer "token_goes_here"
Bearer token_goes_here
Bearer token="token_goes_here"
Bearer token=token_goes_here
Token token="token_goes_here"
Token token=token_goes_here
Token "token_goes_here"
Token token_goes_here
```

I'm sure this list is not exhaustive, but hopefully gives an idea of what is possible.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use

```rb
request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
```

Comment: it's bug prone because it will be throw exception if header is not given or not string

Comment: @Nozim request.headers will always return an object that responds to `[]` (see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers ; so, you could simple improve make it safer: `request.headers['Authorization'].to_s.split(' ').last`